# Selecting second children of first div children in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, getelementbyid

I have an html that look something like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv"> <-- I have this
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div> <-- I need to get this
    </div>
    <span></span>
    <more stuff />
</div>
```

i am using:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
```

because I need that div in a var, but i also need to get that second div on the first div inside mainDiv into a variable.

How could I do it in a simple cross-browser way?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming that structure is static you can do this:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv'),
    childDiv = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    requiredDiv = childDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
```

Further reading: [`.getElementsByTagName()` (from MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: This works perfectly. Straight to the point, I love it :)

Answer (score 37):

```
 var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
 var x = mainDiv.children[0].children[1];
```

or

```
 var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
 var x = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
```

Comment: children[0] works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: children[0] works as expected for me. Thank you This helped me a lot

Answer (score 17):

I would go simply with just one line of vanilla code.

Works for any elements, is not limited to the tag names you have in the structure. But the number of elements and the hierarchy must be preserved.

```
var requiredDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv').firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling;
```

Answer (score 11):

I would pick jQuery and end up with something like this:

```
var getThis = $('#mainDiv > div:eq(0) > div:eq(1)');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7RAq/)

Comment: can you do this in vanillajs yet?

Answer (score 2):

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
var div = maindiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[2];//third div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MGVw8/

Answer (score 1):

You know there is `querySelector` now ?

```js
console.log(
  mainDiv.querySelector(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2)'))
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>come get me</div>
  </div>
  <!-- more stuff -->
</div>
```

Comment: Useful approach. But the tone seems condescending.