# Selecting an nth child - children vs childNodes property

Tags: javascript

Which is better or what are the differences, when you want to select an nth child?  Please note I do not want to use jQuery.

Comment: You're not very good at searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048273/selecting-second-children-of-first-div-children-in-javascript, http://www.codingforums.com/dom-json-scripting/191794-how-get-second-child-dom.html

Comment: what if it has different tags?

Comment: `element.children[1]`

Comment: Question should be accompanied by [**your code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are having issues with and the relevant HTML mark-up and if possible include a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net), or similar, demonstrating the issue. In addition get to know some good resources and the basics for the language you are working with. The [**W3.org on scripts**](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/script) and the [**MDN on JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) are a good start.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you don't provide much information, but you've got two ways:

Let `node` be a DOM node:

```
node.childNodes[1]; //0 is the first child.
```

Another way...

```
node.querySelector(':nth-child(2)'); //in selectors, the first child has index 1.
```

Comment: should I use `childNodes` or `children` per FelixKing in the comments above?

Comment: @user3293082: `children` will give you only elements (which is likely what you want); `childNodes` will give you elements and text nodes and comment nodes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right. .querySelector() will give you only elements, too.